# How to detect call hang up in windows phone 10

Tags: c#, windows-phone, uwp

I want to programmatically detect when call hang up in UWP app for windows phone 10.

I see [Caller ID sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CallerID) and see [Communication blocking and filtering sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CommunicationBlockAndFilter) too.

But I don't find simple solution for detect when call hang up. I found [CallHistoryChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.calls.background.phonetriggertype.aspx) trigger and I think my complex solution is read call history when call history changed trigger and get last incoming call.

Is there any simple solution for detect call hang up?

Is my solution is correct?
Is there a better solution than my solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any simple solution for detect call hang up?
> Is my solution is correct? Is there a better solution than my solution?

As far as I know, there is no other simple solution for detect calls' hang up.

There is an event [PhoneCallManager.CallStateChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.calls.phonecallmanager.callstatechanged.aspx), which can also detect hang up like below:

```
private bool callCame = false;

PhoneCallManager.CallStateChanged += PhoneCallManager_CallStateChanged;

private async void PhoneCallManager_CallStateChanged(object sender, object e)
{
    if (callCame&&(!PhoneCallManager.IsCallActive))
    {
        //do something
    }
    if (PhoneCallManager.IsCallIncoming)
    {
        callCame = true;
    }
}
```

But I don't think it's better than `CallHistoryChanged` trigger. And it won't get you the last Hang up phone's number either.

> Is my solution is correct?

So yes, your solution is correct.

**Update:** There is no trick here. Register the BackgroundTask:

```
private void btnClick_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var taskRegistered = false;
    var exampleTaskName = "MyBackgroundTask";

    foreach (var task in BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks)
    {
        if (task.Value.Name == exampleTaskName)
        {
            taskRegistered = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!taskRegistered)
    {
        var builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();

        builder.Name = exampleTaskName;
        builder.TaskEntryPoint = "PhoneCallBackground.Class1";
        builder.SetTrigger(new PhoneTrigger(Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls.Background.PhoneTriggerType.CallHistoryChanged, false));
            builder.Register();
    }
}
```

And don't forget to register it in the appxmanifest file:
[image]

The `Run` Method will be fired after you hang up, if you registered the BackgroundTask. `PhoneCallManager` can not be registered for BackgroundTask. You need to set it as the default PhoneCall App, if you want to use this.

**Update2:**

I checked the demo, you are still using `PhoneTriggerType.CallOriginDataRequest` to register the background task. Please change it to `PhoneTriggerType.CallHistoryChanged`. And also make sure the registered background task is unregistered after you making any change to your codes.

Here is the demo that I modified: [CallHistoryChangeTest](https://github.com/elvisxia/CallHistoryChangedTest).

Comment: Can you explain some example for use `CallHistoryChanged`? when I register this trigger for some background task this trigger does not fire any time. does exist any trick for this?

Comment: How to use `PhoneCallManager` for register a trigger for BackgroundTask?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response, but how to set it as the default? I cannot found my app name in Calling list or Calling & Messaging list

Comment: I created a sample xamarin forms project and deploy UWP projects and I see `Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(1930,5): warning APPX0104: Certificate file 'Windows_TemporaryKey.pfx' not found.` 
`Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(1930,5): warning APPX0107: The certificate specified is not valid for signing. For more information about valid certificates, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=241478.` warning. is it important?

Comment: I created simple sample in [GitHub](https://github.com/soroshsabz/CallHistoryChangedTest), I will be happy if you tell me my mistake.

Comment: Well, you should put your `CallHangupTask.cs` into a Windows Runtime Component, which is a separate project and should be referenced by your main project. Please see [Create and register a background task that runs in a separate process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/create-and-register-a-background-task).

Comment: Thank for replay again, I create separate Windows Runtime Component project and put CallHangupTask into project, but it is not work again. I commit new code in git again.

Comment: Please use `PhoneTriggerType.CallHistoryChanged` to register the background task. Please check my update 2 in the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, for your help, at the end this trigger is work but two question is exists yet, why after call to phone and hang up I received two or tree trigger fire? and another why my app is not exist in call default app list yet?